# Yacas apparently computes one-sided limit wrong

Tags: limit, infinity, yacas

I want to find

```
lim(x->4-) ((x-4)/(x^2-8*x+16))
```

so I typed this into the Yacas interface:

```
Limit(x,4,Right) (1/(x-4))
```

Yacas answered:

```
Infinity
```

But that is wrong; the answer is -Infinity.  Am I just misunderstanding the *dir* argument of the Limit() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just messing up your notation. Think back to calculus:

```
lim x goes to 4 of f(x) is two limits:
    lim x goes to 4- of f(x)
    lim x goes to 4+ of f(x)
```

If both of those limits exist, then lim x goes to 4 exists. However, you have the directions backwards. The lim as x goes to `4-` means from the left. The lim as x goes to `4+` means from the right.

```
Limit(x,4,Right) (1/(x-4)) == Infinity (lim x goes to 4+)
Limit(x,4,Left) (1/(x-4)) == -Infinity (lim x goes to 4-)
```

[image: graph of y = 1/(x-4)]

Comment: Thanks, Roy, that makes sense.  The Yacas manual is written backwards for Limit(); it says 'If one gives "dir" the value Left, the limit is taken as "var" approaches "val" from the positive infinity; and Right will take the limit from the negative infinity.'

Comment: @StevePfeiffer What does it say?

Comment: Sorry hit "Return" too soon

Comment: @StevePfeiffer That's really weird.